# Elasticsearch Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch, datatables

I am trying to run functions from an elasticsearch instance through to datatables to display results.

I am only getting 10 to show and no matter the query I get the same 10 all the time. Currently there are 141,000 results in elasticsearch but only able to read 10 in datatables.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elasticsearch/10.0.1/elasticsearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery.elastic-datatables.js"></script>
<script>
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200'
    });


    $('#orders').dataTable({
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'columns': [
            { 'sTitle': 'Order Code', 'sName': 'channel_order_code' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Created', 'sName': 'created_at' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Order ID', 'sName': 'po_number' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Tracking', 'sName': 'tracking' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Name', 'sName': 'bill_to_name' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Phone', 'sName': 'customer_phone' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Email', 'sName': 'customer_email' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Group ID', 'sName': 'group_id' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Order Status', 'sName': 'status' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Upload Status', 'sName': 'upload_status' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Subtotal', 'sName': 'subtotal_amount' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Shipping', 'sName': 'channel' },
            { 'sTitle': 'State', 'sName': 'state' }
        ],
        'fnServerData': $.fn.dataTable.elastic_datatables( {
            index: 'orders',
            type:'logs',
            client,
            body: {
                query: {
                    match_all: {

                    }
                }
            }
        } )
</script>
```

When I go to the url and enter /orders/_search?q=* I get the full results, however, through this I get 10. When I put in _search or search in the 'type' I get nothing, when I remove 'type' I get the same 10.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the package using for jquery.elastic-datatables.js https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 is the default number of results returned from Elasitcsearch.

Querying ES directly, you can increase the number of results with `size` or add an offset with `from`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Please don't forget the default maximum size is 10.000. Please utilize `from` if you need a bigger data. You can change the maximum size from the `index.max_result_window` setting though.

Based on the description here: https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables/ you don't need to mess with `size`/`from` in the ES query directly, and can request `n` results by specifying the `aoData.length` parameter for `DataTables`.

You should be able to request the next `n` by including the `aoData.start` parameter: https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables/blob/7bb98580add1c3b58fdf776426606c5fe65a1deb/src/jquery.elastic-datatables.js#L33-L34

Comment: I know I shouldn't however I am still getting just 10 results, the count on the footer of datatables should show the hits from ES, and are showing Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries. Even when I use a size/from setting manually.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. I'm not seeing the a `POST` body going to ES as part of the request, which would cause the behavior you described. Are you seeing it on your end?

Comment: I am not seeing post going through on my end

Comment: Meaning no HTTP request, or no body?

Comment: I am getting no POST request, just GET.

Comment: Not sure if it is an issue with the build process in the library, but was able to get the request to work (i.e. a POST with a valid body) after copying the source directly from github and commenting out the `sort` line: https://gist.github.com/geoff616/3262980b167cb8d8d2bcI've Changing that allows changing the number of results returned, but pagination still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I would recommend filing an issue w/ the library if this doesn't resolve your problem. Good luck!